# Problem with parallelism. I need help for a simple async await usage

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I try to understand why my code is exiting before running all parts of my code. I understand I must do something wrong with async await but I cannot figure out what:

Here is my main method. Note the Logger. I use NLog and I redirect my log to my console. Note the 2 lines where I log and the line where I call my scheduler service.

```
{
    Logger.Info("Monitoring Started");
    var monitorer = new Monitorer();
    monitorer.ScheduleService();
    Logger.Info("Done");
}
```

My class Monitorer with the schedule service class:

```
public class Monitorer
{
    private Logger Logger { get; } = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    public async void ScheduleService()
    {
        Logger.Trace(nameof(ScheduleService));

        // Instantiate TaskEvaluationRuntime.
        var runtime = new TaskEvaluationRuntime();
        var s1 = new ScheduleRule()
            .AtMinutes(30)
            .WithName("CheckoutTasks")
            .Execute((_, _) => { new Monitoring.UpdateCheckoutDate().Run(); return true; });

        var s2 = new ScheduleRule()
            .AtMinutes(30)
            .WithName("CheckoutTasks")
            .Execute((_, _) => { new Monitoring.UpdateOrderTag().Run(); return true; });

        // Add the schedules to the runtime.
        runtime.AddSchedule(s1);
        runtime.AddSchedule(s2);

        // Await the runtime.
        Logger.Trace("Await the runtime.");
        await runtime.RunAsync();

        // Listen for some signal to quit.
        Logger.Trace("Listen for some signal to quit.");
        Thread.Sleep(30000);

        // Graceful shutdown. Request a stop and await running tasks.
        Logger.Trace("Graceful shutdown. Request a stop and await running tasks.");
        await runtime.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

I use a Nuget package named Task Scheduler Engine. In this code I create a scheduled task s1 and s2.

Here is the result of my console:

```
2023-02-27 14:58:21.8067
2023-02-27 14:58:21.8304 Monitoring Started
2023-02-27 14:58:21.9111 ScheduleService
2023-02-27 14:58:21.9111 Await the runtime.
2023-02-27 14:58:21.9195 Done
```

Any idea why `Logger.Trace("Listen for some signal to quit.");` and `Logger.Trace("Graceful shutdown. Request a stop and await running tasks.");` are not executed?

Comment: `async void` is not awaitable, so your Program exits before the Method is finished. Change it to `async Task` and await it.

Comment: You also want to replace this `Thread.Sleep(30000);` by `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`